# Requested page not found: Cannot transform this request's content - CannotTransformContentToTypeException

Tags: kotlin, http-post, ktor

New to Kotlin and Ktor. I am trying to add a post request handler.

The data class ***EmployeeDTO*** is as follows

```
@Serializable
data class EmployeeDTO(val empName: String)
```

and ***Routing.kt*** looks like following

```
fun Application.configureRouting(databaseConnection: Connection?) {

    install(StatusPages) {
        exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
            call.respondText(text = "500: $cause" , status = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
        }
        status(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { call, status ->
            println("Requested page not found: ".plus(call.request.uri))
        }
    }
    routing {
        post(getEnvVarValue("BASE_URL").plus("/test")) {
            try{
                val employeeDTO = call.receive<EmployeeDTO>()
            }catch(t:Throwable){
                println("Requested page not found: ".plus(t.message))
            }

            call.respondText("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Now using postman when I make a POST request with following url and data

***url:*** `http://localhost:8080/base-url/test`
***body:*** `{"empName":"testabc"}`

Then I am getting following error

> Requested page not found: Cannot transform this request's content to
> xx.xxx.xxxx.EmployeeDTO

I tried to google this issue and the most prevalent solution is adding ContentNegotiation. However, in ***Serialization.kt***, it is already added like this

```
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }
```

Any solution would be really appreciated. If I remove try/catch block then it is working fine and return string "Test".

Comment: Can you please check that the method that installs the `ContentNegotiation` plugin is actually called?

Comment: When I add the same method in Routing.kt, then it complains about duplicate dependency.

Comment: Can you please try decoding the request body with the `Json.decodeFromString<EmployeeDTO>(call.receiveText())` line of code?